# how do I figure out the hash rate of my computer?

Tags: hashpower, mining-hardware

My computer has

```
   AMD A4-5300 APU W/ Radeon(tm)HD  subscore 6.2
   Graphics AMD Radeon HD 7480D              4.7
```

If any one can help , thank you!

Comment: To know for sure: test it!  But which coin were you thinking of mining: Bitcoin. or something else?  Bitcoin mining will not be economical with any general-purpose computer.  Also, can you clean up the formatting of your question?

Comment: Also, unless you have some very obscure altcoin in mind, you will be mining with your GPU if at all, so all the other information is irrelevant and you might as well remove it.

Answer (score 1):

[Bitminter](https://bitminter.com/test) has a Java test that, among other things, can give you an idea of your hash rate.